# How can i check dictionary value is available in list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to check whether the value of **a** exists in the value **b** or not

```
a = [{ "shopid": "store4400013","prd_category": "Chicken","product_id":"4359197","prd_name":"Chicken chilli","prod_type":"Non_Veg","prd_amt":"100.0"}]

b = [{'shopid': 'store4400013', 'prd_category': 'Chicken', 'product_id': 4359197, 'prd_name': 'Chicken chilli', 'prod_type': 'Non_Veg', 'prd_amt': 100.0, 'image': '/media/abhishek/e/Moneypay/merchant/mxuserimage/menu_3418906783.png'}, {'shopid': 'store4400013', 'prd_category': 'Chicken', 'product_id': 6911213, 'prd_name': 'Chicken kadai', 'prod_type': 'Non_Veg', 'prd_amt': 250.0, 'image': '/media/abhishek/e/Moneypay/merchant/mxuserimage/menu_3890935432.png'}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `value of a`? Are there specific key-value pairs which need to be identical?

Comment: sorry i mean variable a and variable b

Comment: Why have a list of one dictionary?

Comment: @RoadRunner..Because I am getting variable a as a response and there will be any number dictionary in list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a value of  `dictionary` of `list a` exists in the values of `dictionary` in list b then:

```
a = [{ "shopid": "store4400013","prd_category": "Chicken","product_id":"4359197","prd_name":"Chicken chilli","prod_type":"Non_Veg","prd_amt":"100.0"}]

b = [{'shopid': 'store4400013', 'prd_category': 'Chicken', 'product_id': 4359197, 'prd_name': 'Chicken chilli', 'prod_type': 'Non_Veg', 'prd_amt': 100.0, 'image': '/media/abhishek/e/Moneypay/merchant/mxuserimage/menu_3418906783.png'}, {'shopid': 'store4400013', 'prd_category': 'Chicken', 'product_id': 6911213, 'prd_name': 'Chicken kadai', 'prod_type': 'Non_Veg', 'prd_amt': 250.0, 'image': '/media/abhishek/e/Moneypay/merchant/mxuserimage/menu_3890935432.png'}]

all_values_of_a = [i[key] for i in a for key in i.keys()]
all_values_of_b = [i[key] for i in b for key in i.keys()]

for i in all_values_of_a:
    if i in all_values_of_b:
        print(i + " exists")
    else:
        print(i +" does not exist")
```

Or if you want to check whether a value of `list a` exists in `list b` or not then:

```
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        print(i +" exists")
    else:
        print(i +" does not exits")
```